# QWebView in thread - Pyside

Tags: multithreading, pyqt, qwebview

I would like to know if someone knows how to reload a QWebView in Pyside inside a thread every 30seconds for examples. For now, I have that code inside my thread running as daemon:

```
while(1):
    # Every 30 seconds
    for in in range(0,30):
        time.sleep(0.01)

    # Reload the page
     self.webView.reload()
```

The issues is this error message and i don't know how to solve it:

```
Qobject cannot creat thread network psyide
parent is qnetworkaccessmanager parent's thread is qthread
```

If someone have an idea, i'm stuck

Comment: Use a `QTimer`, not a thread.

Comment: In fact, the timer is working, the issue is the reload() function. It's the reload function that create the error message every time the function is called

Comment: Qt does not support gui operations outside the main thread. Use a [QTimer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html), not a thread.